# php8.0-json library not found when updating Pi-hole

Tags: php

When updating pi-hole I got a message:

```
Checking for php8.0-intl (will be installed)
Processing apt-get install(s) for: php8.0-cgi php8.0-json php8.0-intl, please wait...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E: Package 'php8.0-json' has no installation candidate
```

Recently I installed php8.0 on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I did apt update & upgrade, but the php8.0-json is still not available.
Anyway, Pi-hole still works flawlessly, but I cannot update. Is there a way to install this json ?

Answer (score 2):

Version 8 has moved json into core code and it is no longer a separate module.

Full details can be seen on PHP Watch [here](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/ext-json)

As for getting PiHole running fully, you may find [their forum](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/) more help as it's not a Pi specific program / issue as PHP 8 is not shipped by default yet.

**Edit:**

To install php 8.0 add the repository:

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt update
```

Then install the base and cli:

```
sudo apt install -y php8.0-common php8.0-cli
```

Then install the required modules:

```
sudo apt install -y php8.0-extension_name
```

e.g. for cURL and zip:

```
sudo apt install -y php8.0-curl php8.0-zip
```

For Apache use one / both of:

```
sudo apt install -y libapache2-mod-php8.0
sudo apt install -y php8.0-fpm
```

Full changed details start at [this page](https://php.watch/versions/8.0)

**BE WARNED**

1. The above does not replace earlier versions and may cause your scripts to fail if they are version dependant. You should remove earlier versions of PHP first using *sudo apt purge '^php7.x.*'* where 'x' is the sub-version of 7 installed (often 7.3 on Zeros and 7.4 on 2+ boards)
2. I have not tried both versions together, nor have I tried *sudo
   update-alternatives --config php* to switch between them.
3. I do not believe v8.x will run on early ARMv6 chip sets (e.g. Pi 1 / zero / zero W) - you would need to compile the source yourself.

Note:

- There is no JSON component now as it's built in so any references to the file php8.0-json will **ERROR**.
- Checks within PHP scripts for the module being loaded using extension_loaded('json') or function_exists('json_decode') will **PASS**
- See [here](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/ext-json) for full details

Answer (score 0):

On the Raspberry Pi forum I found this solution:
https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pihole-5-php-8/44609 (German).

I uninstalled PHP 8, did update Pihole (pihole -up) successfully and kicked the RP 4 and after the reboot it ran flawlessly using PHP 7.4.

Is there a way to install a complete PHP 8 with builtin JSON ?

Comment: I've added notes on installing PHP 8.0 for you.